# jQuery .show() method not working inside .click function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Below is code that is supposed to make a text box appear/disappear based on whether or not a box is checked (the text box is hidden when the page loads). All the alerts are firing properly, however I cannot get the check box to `.show()` function to work.

Here is the jQuery. This from inside the `document.ready` function. You can see from what I've commented out the other two methods I've tried (neither worked).

```
    $('#OverrideRegionInd').click(function () {
        alert($(this).is(':checked'));
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("inside if");
            $('#Region').show();
            //$('#Region').css("display", "inline");
            // $('#Region').toggle();
            $('#territoryName').html("");
            $('#Region').val("");

        } else {
            alert("inside else");
            $('#Region').hide();
            //$('#Region').css("display", "none");
            // $('#Region').toggle();
        }
    });
```

Here is the code from the view

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region)
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field" id="territoryName">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Region, new { style = "display: none;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Region)
    </div>
```

Here is the HTML once the page is rendered for this particular set of `<div>`'s

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        <label for="Region">Territory</label>
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field" id="territoryName">
        <input id="Region" name="Region" style="display: none;" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Region" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: just a heads up, you can do the same thing with `if(this.checked)` ... way less overhead than `$(this).is(':checked')`.

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the same id?

Comment: just a heads up, you can do `$('#Region').toggle(this.checked)` without an if / else condition, way less overhead ?

Comment: `$('#Region').closest('div').show()`. Try this.

Comment: @Omar - how would showing the closest div help, when the input is hidden ?

Comment: You could write the code as    `$('#OverrideRegionInd').click(function () {
            $('#Region').toggle(this.checked).val("");
            $('#territoryName').html("");
    });`
if the html and value can be reset in either case. `toggle` is great

Comment: @adeneo it depends on how the input is hidden from the beginning. Jquery wraps inputs with divs.

Comment: @Omar - jQuery does what now ?

Comment: @adeneo it does magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're setting:

```
$('#territoryName').html("");
```

That's the parent of `#Region`, you're effectively **removing the `#Region` element** with that line. Take that out and it'll work fine.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9h3/)